# uni test 404 failure response with angular service + jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written a service which handles data with API. I have completed `success response`unit testing for the same but facing issues with Unit Test of  `404 Error Response`.

*Please update answer with real scenarios as per question. I have already scene few tutorials but those are not helpful.*

Here is my service code:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('SizingService',
    function (SizerGatewayApi, RestDomains, $q, UnitySizerService) {

        let api = new SizerGatewayApi(GatewayUrl);

        return {
            postSizingResults: postSizingResults
        };

        function postSizingResults(unitySizerDTO) {
            let deferred = $q.defer();

            function handleSuccessResponse(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                UnitySizerService.resultSummary = data;
            }

            function handleErrorResponse(response) {
                //Not able to cover UT for 404
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.body);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                }
            }

            api.post({dto: unitySizerDTO}).then(handleSuccessResponse, handleErrorResponse);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
);
```

Here is my spec file

```
describe('SizingService', function () {

        beforeEach(module('basic-unity-replication-sizer-ui'));

        let data = {
            //    response data
        };

        let SizerGatewayApiStub;
        let unitySizerDTO = {
            //post dto
        };

        let rootScope;
        let $scope;
        let SizingService;
        let $q;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module(function ($provide) {
                SizerGatewayApiStub = function () {
                    this.post = function (value) {
                        let deferred = $q.defer();
                        if (value.dto !== 'failure') {
                            deferred.resolve({data: data});
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject("no data");
                        }
                        return deferred.promise;
                    };
                };

                $provide.value('SizerGatewayApi', SizerGatewayApiStub);
            });

            inject(function (_$q_, $rootScope, _SizingService_) {
                $q = _$q_;
                rootScope = $rootScope;
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                SizingService = _SizingService_;
            });
        });

        describe('should handle response', function () {
            it('success', inject(function (SizingService) {
                SizingService.postSizingResults(unitySizerDTO);
                $scope.$apply();
                expect(data).toBeDefined();
                expect(data).not.toBeNull();
            }));

            //404 Failure scenarios needs to be covered by UT
            it('failure', inject(function (SizingService) {
                SizingService.postSizingResults(postWrongDTO);
                $scope.$apply();
            }));
        });

    });
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Want to unit test success and failure scenarios of above service.

Comment: how to unit test these function `function handleSuccessResponse(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                UnitySizerService.resultSummary = data;
            }

            function handleErrorResponse(response) {
                //Not able to cover UT for 404
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.body);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                }
            }`

Comment: You need to state the problem clearly.

Comment: Why would you want to successfully resolve promise for `500` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually having a difficult time understanding your code but what I "think"  you will want to do is put a spy on SizerGateWayApiStub.post and return the rejected promise.

Something like this should get you on the correct path:

Add a variable `let postDeferred;`

Then in your beforeEach inject you will want to set up the spy

```
postDeferred = $q.defer();
spyOn(SizerGatewayApiStub, 'post').and.returnValue(postDeferred.promise);
```

Then in your test you would do something like this

```
it('failure', inject(function (SizingService) {  
        let mockResponse = {
            status = "404",
            body = "somevalue"
        };

        let result = SizingService.postSizingResults(postWrongDTO);
        postDeferred.reject(mockResponse);
        $scope.$apply();
        expect(SizerGatewayApiStub.post).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toEqual(mockResponse.body);            
    }));
});
```